# SQL Server - Querying for Closest Date Range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I have a table structure like this:

```
ProductCode  Date
Foo          4/1/2012
Foo          4/2/2012
Foo          4/3/2012
Foo          4/6/2012
Foo          4/7/2012
Foo          4/8/2012
Foo          4/9/2012
Foo          4/10/2012
Foo          4/15/2012
Foo          4/16/2012
Foo          4/17/2012
```

Is there a way to query for the date range for a given `ProductCode` and `Date` (assuming that ranges MUST be sequential)? In other words, for this table, Foo exists on 3 date ranges: `4/1-4/3`; `4/6-4/10`; and `4/15-4/17` and I'm looking for the date range given a date.

Please note that `Foo` doesn't have date's `4/4`, `4/5`, `4/11`, `4/12`, `4/13` and `4/14`.

Examples:
`ProductCode=Foo, Date=4/2` would return `4/1-4/3` because the entries are sequential.
`ProductCode=Foo, Date=4/4` would return nothing
`ProductCode=Foo, Date=4/7` would return `4/6-4/10` because the entries are sequential.
`ProductCode=Foo, Date=4/12` would return nothing
etc.

Comment: I think SQL Server 2005. He/she has two questions with [sql-server-2005] tag.

Answer (score 1):

A new range starts when there is no row for the previous day.  If you are running SQL Server 2012, you can use the `lag` window function to check if a row introduces a new range.  Once you know which rows introduce a new range, you can count the number of head rows to assign a unique number to each range.

Having a range number allows you to find the start and end date with `min` and `max`.  After that, it's just a question of selecting the row:

```
; with  IsHead as
        (
        select  ProductCode
        ,       Date
        ,       case when lag(Date) over (partition by ProductCode 
                  order by Date) = dateadd(day, -1, Date) then 0 
                  else 1 end as IsHead
        from  YourTable
        )
,       RangeNumber as
        (
        select  ProductCode
        ,       Date
        ,       sum(IsHead) over (partition by ProductCode order by Date) 
                  as RangeNr
        from    IsHead
        )
,       Ranges as
        (
        select  *
        ,       min(Date) over (partition by RangeNr) as RangeStart
        ,       max(Date) over (partition by RangeNr) as RangeEnd
        from    RangeNumber
        )
select  *
from    Ranges
where   ProductCode = 'Bar'
        and Date = '4/2/2012'
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/211f0/1)

Comment: Doesn't compile. `Incorrect syntax near 'order'.` `Order` is not allowed in the `over` clause for aggregate window functions such as `sum`.

Comment: @GSerg: You're probably using an old SQL Server version.  The SQL Fiddle example works.

Comment: @GSerg The `OVER` clause for aggregates was introduced in SQL Server 2012 (good for running totals)

Comment: @MartinSmith No, it was introduced earlier, but 2012 allowed `order` in `over`. I didn't know that. The chances are the OP is not using 2012 though.

Answer (score 1):

Could have used LAG, if SQL Server 2005 supported it. Unfortunately [LAG window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) works on SQL Server 2012 only, and [PostgreSQL 8.4 and above](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) ;-)

Works on SQL Server 2005 I supposed, SQLFiddle has no SQL 2005 support, tried SQLFiddle's SQL Server 2008 only, not 2012:

```
with DetectLeaders as
(
    select cr.ProductCode, CurRowDate = cr.Date, PrevRowDate = pr.Date
    from tbl cr
    left join tbl pr 
    on pr.ProductCode = cr.ProductCode AND cr.Date = DATEADD(DAY,1,pr.Date)
),
MembersLeaders as
(
    select *, 
        MemberLeader = 
            (select top 1 CurRowDate 
            from DetectLeaders nearest
            where nearest.PrevRowDate is null 
                and nearest.ProductCode = DetectLeaders.ProductCode
                and DetectLeaders.CurRowDate >= nearest.CurRowDate 
            order by nearest.CurRowDate desc)   
    from DetectLeaders
)
select BeginDate = MIN(CurRowDate), EndDate = MAX(CurRowDate) 
from MembersLeaders
where MemberLeader = 
  (select MemberLeader 
   from MembersLeaders
   where ProductCode = 'Foo' and CurRowDate = '4/7/2012')
```

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fd1f/1

---

Basically this is how it works:

```
PRODUCTCODE     CURROWDATE  PREVROWDATE MEMBERLEADER
Foo             2012-04-01              2012-04-01
Foo             2012-04-02  2012-04-01  2012-04-01
Foo             2012-04-03  2012-04-02  2012-04-01
Foo             2012-04-06              2012-04-06
Foo             2012-04-07  2012-04-06  2012-04-06
Foo             2012-04-08  2012-04-07  2012-04-06
Foo             2012-04-09  2012-04-08  2012-04-06
Foo             2012-04-10  2012-04-09  2012-04-06
Foo             2012-04-15              2012-04-15
Foo             2012-04-16  2012-04-15  2012-04-15
Foo             2012-04-17  2012-04-16  2012-04-15
Bar             2012-05-01              2012-05-01
Bar             2012-05-02  2012-05-01  2012-05-01
Bar             2012-05-03  2012-05-02  2012-05-01
Bar             2012-05-06              2012-05-06
Bar             2012-05-07  2012-05-06  2012-05-06
Bar             2012-05-08  2012-05-07  2012-05-06
Bar             2012-05-09  2012-05-08  2012-05-06
Bar             2012-05-10  2012-05-09  2012-05-06
Bar             2012-05-15              2012-05-15
Bar             2012-05-16  2012-05-15  2012-05-15
Bar             2012-05-17  2012-05-16  2012-05-15
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35818/11

Answer (score 0):

Could do with a recursive CTE.

```
declare @target_date datetime = convert(datetime, '04/07/2012', 101);

with source_table as (
  select ProductCode, convert(datetime, Date, 101) as Date
  from (
    values
    ('Foo', '4/1/2012')
   ,('Foo', '4/2/2012')
   ,('Foo', '4/3/2012')
   ,('Foo', '4/6/2012')
   ,('Foo', '4/7/2012')
   ,('Foo', '4/8/2012')
   ,('Foo', '4/9/2012')
   ,('Foo', '4/10/2012')
   ,('Foo', '4/15/2012')
   ,('Foo', '4/16/2012')
   ,('Foo', '4/17/2012')
  ) foo(ProductCode, Date)
),
recursive_date_lower as (
  select Date from source_table where Date = @target_date

  union all

  select dateadd(d, -1, r.Date) from recursive_date_lower r where exists (select 0 from source_table s where s.Date = dateadd(d, -1, r.Date))
),
recursive_date_upper as (
  select Date from source_table where Date = @target_date

  union all

  select dateadd(d, 1, r.Date) from recursive_date_upper r where exists (select 0 from source_table s where s.Date = dateadd(d, 1, r.Date))
)
select
   (select min(Date) from recursive_date_lower) as start,
   (select max(Date) from recursive_date_upper) as finish
```

Comment: Doesn't run at all on SQL 2005. I don't think you can declare a variable like that in 2005 and 'values' doesn't stand on its own without 'insert', at least afaik!

Comment: @JamesJiao It's syntax sugar introduced in 2008. It's irrelevant to the example, you're supposed to remove the `source_table` CTE and replace its name in the query with the actual table name. Variable declaration can be split into two lines (declaration then assignment).

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I have added a second solution (non-recursive) which has less logical reads (better performance).

1. You could use a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)(demo [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/67478)):

   DECLARE @Test TABLE
   (
   ID          INT IDENTITY NOT NULL UNIQUE, --ID is for insert order
   ProductCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   [Date]      SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(ProductCode, [Date])
   );

   INSERT  @Test (ProductCode , [Date])
   SELECT 'Foo' , '20120401'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120402'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120403'

   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120404'
   --UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120405'

   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120406'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120407'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120408'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120409'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120410'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120415'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120416'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120417';

   DECLARE @MyProductCode VARCHAR(10),
   @MyDate SMALLDATETIME;

   SELECT  @MyProductCode = 'Foo',
   @MyDate = '20120402';

   WITH    CteRecursive
   AS
   (
   --Starting row
   SELECT  t.ID,
   t.ProductCode,
   t.[Date],
   1 AS RowType
   FROM    @Test t
   WHERE   t.ProductCode = @MyProductCode
   AND     t.[Date] = @MyDate
   UNION ALL
   --Add the next days DATEADD(DAY, +1, ..)
   SELECT  crt.ID,
   crt.ProductCode,
   crt.[Date],
   2 AS RowType
   FROM    CteRecursive prev
   INNER JOIN @Test crt ON DATEADD(DAY, 1, prev.[Date]) = crt.[Date] AND prev.RowType IN (1,2)
   UNION ALL
   --Add the previous days DATEADD(DAY, -1, ..)
   SELECT  crt.ID,
   crt.ProductCode,
   crt.[Date],
   0 AS RowType
   FROM    CteRecursive prev
   INNER JOIN @Test crt ON DATEADD(DAY, -1, prev.[Date]) = crt.[Date] AND prev.RowType IN (0,1)
   )
   SELECT  *
   FROM    CteRecursive r
   ORDER BY r.[Date]
   /*--Or
   SELECT  MIN(r.[Date]) AS BeginDate, MAX(r.[Date]) AS EndDate
   FROM    CteRecursive r
   */

Results:

```
ID          ProductCode Date                    RowType
----------- ----------- ----------------------- -------
1           Foo         2012-04-01 00:00:00     0
2           Foo         2012-04-02 00:00:00     1
3           Foo         2012-04-03 00:00:00     2
4           Foo         2012-04-04 00:00:00     2
```

2. Non-recursive solution:

   DECLARE @Test TABLE
   (
   ProductCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   [Date]      SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(ProductCode, [Date])
   );

   INSERT  @Test (ProductCode , [Date])
   SELECT 'Foo' , '20120401'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120402'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120403'

   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120404'
   --UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120405'

   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120406'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120407'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120408'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120409'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120410'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120415'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120416'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo' , '20120417';

   DECLARE @MyProductCode VARCHAR(10),
   @MyDate SMALLDATETIME;

   SELECT  @MyProductCode = 'Foo',
   @MyDate = '20120402';

   DECLARE @StartDate SMALLDATETIME,
   @EndDate SMALLDATETIME;

   SELECT  @EndDate = MAX(b.[Date])
   FROM
   (
   SELECT  a.[Date],
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.Date ASC)-1 AS RowNum
   FROM    @Test a
   WHERE   a.ProductCode = @MyProductCode
   AND     a.[Date] >= @MyDate
   ) b
   WHERE   b.[Date] = DATEADD(DAY, b.RowNum, @MyDate);

   SELECT  @StartDate = MIN(b.[Date])
   FROM
   (
   SELECT  a.[Date],
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.Date DESC)-1 AS RowNum
   FROM    @Test a
   WHERE   a.ProductCode = @MyProductCode
   AND     a.[Date] <= @MyDate
   ) b
   WHERE   b.[Date] = DATEADD(DAY, -b.RowNum, @MyDate);

   SELECT  @StartDate [@StartDate], @EndDate [@EndDate];
   SELECT  LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @StartDate, 101),5) [@StartDate], LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @EndDate, 101),5) [@EndDate];

Results:

```
@StartDate              @EndDate
----------------------- -----------------------
2012-04-01 00:00:00     2012-04-04 00:00:00

@StartDate @EndDate
---------- --------
04/01      04/04
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (assuming SQL Server 2005+):

```
WITH partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    ProductCode,
    Date,
    GroupID = DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Date)
            - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductCode ORDER BY Date)
  FROM atable
),
ranges AS (
  SELECT
    ProductCode,
    Date,
    MinDate = MIN(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductCode, GroupID),
    MaxDate = MAX(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductCode, GroupID)
  FROM partitioned
)
SELECT
  MinDate,
  MaxDate
FROM ranges
WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode
  AND Date = @Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CROSS APPLY to find the nearest date:

```
with DetectLeaders as
(
    select cr.ProductCode, CurRowDate = cr.Date, PrevRowDate = pr.Date
    from tbl cr
    left join tbl pr 
    on pr.ProductCode = cr.ProductCode AND cr.Date = DATEADD(DAY,1,pr.Date)
),
MembersLeaders as
(
    select *       
    from DetectLeaders
    cross apply(
        select top 1 MemberLeader = CurRowDate 
        from DetectLeaders nearest
        where nearest.PrevRowDate is null 
            and nearest.ProductCode = DetectLeaders.ProductCode
            and DetectLeaders.CurRowDate >= nearest.CurRowDate 
        order by nearest.CurRowDate desc
    ) as xxx
)
select BeginDate = MIN(CurRowDate), EndDate = MAX(CurRowDate) 
from MembersLeaders
where MemberLeader = 
  (select MemberLeader 
   from MembersLeaders
   where ProductCode = 'Foo' and CurRowDate = '4/7/2012')
```

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fd1f/2

---

Basically this is how it works:

```
PRODUCTCODE     CURROWDATE  PREVROWDATE MEMBERLEADER
Foo             2012-04-01              2012-04-01
Foo             2012-04-02  2012-04-01  2012-04-01
Foo             2012-04-03  2012-04-02  2012-04-01
Foo             2012-04-06              2012-04-06
Foo             2012-04-07  2012-04-06  2012-04-06
Foo             2012-04-08  2012-04-07  2012-04-06
Foo             2012-04-09  2012-04-08  2012-04-06
Foo             2012-04-10  2012-04-09  2012-04-06
Foo             2012-04-15              2012-04-15
Foo             2012-04-16  2012-04-15  2012-04-15
Foo             2012-04-17  2012-04-16  2012-04-15
Bar             2012-05-01              2012-05-01
Bar             2012-05-02  2012-05-01  2012-05-01
Bar             2012-05-03  2012-05-02  2012-05-01
Bar             2012-05-06              2012-05-06
Bar             2012-05-07  2012-05-06  2012-05-06
Bar             2012-05-08  2012-05-07  2012-05-06
Bar             2012-05-09  2012-05-08  2012-05-06
Bar             2012-05-10  2012-05-09  2012-05-06
Bar             2012-05-15              2012-05-15
Bar             2012-05-16  2012-05-15  2012-05-15
Bar             2012-05-17  2012-05-16  2012-05-15
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fd1f/3

`CROSS APPLY/OUTER APPLY` compared to JOIN, scales nicely too: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/04/outer-apply-walkthrough.html