# Query to return date range between date row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data structure like this

```
tid     dt
T004    2021-01-05
T004    2021-01-06
T004    2021-01-08
T004    2021-01-10
T004    2021-01-15
T004    2021-01-20
T005    2021-01-01
T005    2021-01-05
```

I want to return a range between row that nearest date like this

```
tid    startDate    endDate
T004    2021-01-05   2021-01-06
T004    2021-01-06   2021-01-08
T004    2021-01-08   2021-01-10
T004    2021-01-10   2021-01-15
T004    2021-01-15   2021-01-20
T005    2021-01-01   2021-01-05
```

I've tried with this approach but this not do a trick

[SQL Server - Querying for Closest Date Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259157/sql-server-querying-for-closest-date-range)

Fiddle Example
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/682dc7f/1

example query

```
INSERT INTO dtterm
    ([tid], [dt])
VALUES
    ('T004', '2021-01-05 00:00:00'),
    ('T004', '2021-01-06 00:00:00'),
    ('T004', '2021-01-08 00:00:00'),
    ('T004', '2021-01-10 00:00:00'),
    ('T004', '2021-01-15 00:00:00'),
    ('T004', '2021-01-20 00:00:00'),
    ('T005', '2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
    ('T005', '2021-01-05 00:00:00')
;
```

Comment: Are you sue you are using SQL Server? Your backtick syntax looks like MySQL. And your fiddle is MySQL.

Comment: @DaleK sorry I generate from fiddle I forget to choose ms SQL server, updated question

Comment: Show us what you actually tried when using the other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LEAD`:

```
select *
from
(
  select
    tid,
    dt as start_date,
    lead(dt) over (partition by tid order by dt) as end_date
  from mytable
) t
where end_date is not null
order by tid, start_date;
```

Comment: Nice one Thorsten Kettner!!